# Column value not getting replaced by the correct data

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code that checks each cell in column D and replaces the value accordingly to the logic. I have gone through the logic, but unable to figure out the error.

[image]

Note : copy pasted the same data in column D from column C

```
 Sub Replace_country()

  Dim val As String
  Dim c As Range
  Dim rng As Range

  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D" & ActiveSheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

  For Each c In rng
    val = c.Value

    If val = "US" Or val = "USA" Or val = "United States" Then
      c.Value = "USA"

    ElseIf val = "India" Or val = "In" Or val = "ind" Then  //Error occurs here
      c.Value = "India"

    Else
      c.Value = "ROW"

    End If
  Next c
 End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean you get an error message? If so, what? I guess you mean just the wrong output - perhaps you have some hidden characters after "India" - try using Trim in the first instance.

Comment: yes, that was the error :) Trimming the extra whitespace character solved this. Thank you